# Convert ul to <select> and <option> and keep class

Tags: jquery

I try to convert a menu (`ul` and `li`s) to `select` and `option` for mobile. I would like to keep the class that are already there for the `<li>`s elements. I can convert them but I don't know how to keep the class from `li` to `option`. How should I do?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
       if ($(window).width() < 639) {
           $('ul#nav').each(function () {
               var list = $(this),
                   select = $(document.createElement('select')).insertBefore($(this).hide());

               $('>li a', this).each(function () {
                   var target = $(this).attr('target'),
                       option = $(document.createElement('option'))
                           .appendTo(select)
                           .val(this.href)
                           .html($(this).html())
                           .click(function () {
                           if (target === '_blank') {
                               window.open($(this).val());
                           } else {
                               window.location.href = $(this).val();
                           }
                       });
               });
               list.remove();
           });
       }
   });
```

Comment: use addClass($(this).attr('class'))

Comment: Inside of `$('>li a', this)` each loop, `$(this).closest('li').attr('class')` gets you the class/classes of the li

Comment: Why `$(document.createElement('option'))` instead of `$("<option>")`? If you're using jQuery, use it consistently.

Comment: Ok great, I used $(this).closest('li').attr('class'), stored it in a variable and used .addClass.

Comment: @LucienDubois if the anchor is an immediate child of li you can also use `.parent()` I used `closest()` to be on the safe side since I cannot see the html you have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the code that you provided, you might try this:

```
$('>li a', this).each(function() {
    var target = $(this).attr('target'),
    var classes = $(this).parent('li').attr('class'), //store the classes in the element
    option = $(document.createElement('option'))
        .appendTo(select)
        .val(this.href)
        .addClass(classes) //add the classes to the new option element
        .html($(this).html())
        ...
```

Comment: I used $(this).closest('li').attr('class') instead of var classes = $(this).attr('class') and it works!

Answer (score 1):

1. You could get a reference to the `li` using [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
2. `class` is an attribute just like `target`. Simply get `class` using `attr()` on the `li`, and save it using `attr()` on the `option`.

I am not giving you code because you are better off writing it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var cls= $(this).attr('class')
```

add this class to `option`

```
$(document.createElement('option'))
                           .appendTo(select)
                           .val(this.href)
                           .html($(this).html()).addClass(cls)
```